# Conditions such that $x→a×\log(b+cx)+d$ has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I have the following problem:

Find conditions on the real numbers $a<0,b>0,c>0,d>0$ such that the function $$x→a×\log(b+cx)+d$$ has a fixed point $x<0$. A similar question can be found in [Conditions on $a>0,b>0,c>0,d<0$ such tha $x→a×log(b+cx)+d$ has a fixed point $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848947/conditions-on-a0-b0-c0-d0-such-tha-x%e2%86%92a%c3%97logbcxd-has-a-fixed-point-x)

However, the method is not applicable for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is increasing and $a\ln(b+cx)+d$ is decreasing (because $\ln$ is increasing and $a<0$), the difference $f(x)=x-[a\ln(b+cx)+d]$ is increasing. Its domain is $(-b/c,\infty)$ which contains $0$, so it suffices to simply check the sign of $f(0)=-a\ln b-d$. If $f(0)\ge0$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, but if $f(0)<0$ then there must exist an $x>0$ for which $f(x)=0$ (since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$).

The same logic can be used to determine if there is a fixed point in $(-b/c,0)$.

Indeed, the difference $f(x)=x-[a\ln(b+cx)+d]$ is increasing and continuous. If $f(0)=-a\ln b-d>0$ then there must exist an $x<0$ for which $f(x)=0$ (since $\lim\limits_{x\to -b/c}f(x)=-\infty$).

Comment: I am asking if we can find $x<0$ as a fixed point.

Comment: @Safwane That's not what you typed in your question.

Comment: Yes. But I asking about all possibilities.

Comment: Your question only asked about $x>0$. Please fix your question to reflect your actual intent. At any rate, the same exact logic can be used for the interval $(-b/c,0)$, so see if you understand the logic.

Comment: I have completed the proof.